# TypeScript cannot find name

Tags: mongoose, typescript, definitelytyped

#### models.d.ts [[mongoose.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts)]

```
/// <reference path='./../../typings/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts' />

import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

// Tried `V0`, `V1`, `V2`, `V3` independently. None worked.

/* V0 */
export interface Foo extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string;
}
```

#### models.ts

```
/// <reference path='./models.d.ts' />

import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export function Foo(model): Foo.Foo /* also tried `Foo` and `models.Foo` */ {
    return mongoose.model('Foo', new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    }));
}
```

[More context + attempts (gist).](https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/dce6e857ea6a394ee913)

### Error

> Cannot find name 'Foo'

As you can see, I even included `reference path` AND `tsconfig.json`, to no avail. How do I import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `reference` tag with external module.

Simply remove reference tag, and write all in `models.ts`

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface IFoo extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string;
}

export var Foo: mongoose.Model<IFoo> =
    mongoose.model<IFoo>('Foo', new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    }));

var foo0: IFoo = new Foo();
```

or external module `foo` in foo.ts

```
export interface Foo extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string;
}
```

and import it in models.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as foo from './foo';

export const Foo: mongoose.Model<foo.Foo> =
    mongoose.model<foo.Foo>('Foo', new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the syntax had moved away from `reference` and towards `import`. I thought that with `tsconfig` we didn't need `reference`, and everything was just visible.